# mongodb pymongo.errors.DocumentTooLarge error

Tags: mongodb, limit

I created a query on mongodb filtering documents for language and data type like this:

```
data = db.my_collection.find({"language": my_language,                              
    "data_type": {"$exists": True}})
```

The query performs without any problems.
Once I add a futher condition like this:

```
data = db.my_collection.find({
    "personal_id": {$nin: [array of ids I dont want to consider]}
    "language": my_language,                              
    "data_type": {"$exists": True}})
```

I get Document too large error. Why so? How can I simply filter only the documents i need? The ids in the array are nearly 800k.

Comment: It means the query inside `find()` is exceeding 16MB, which is the maximum BSON size. The parameter for `find()` is BSON, so it's also limited to this size. The more important question is: why do you need to have 800k terms inside the `$in`? Even if it works, the query will be so slow it's not worth doing. You should rethink the query if it's this big.

Comment: I am trying to translate periodically all the documents from the db, every time i query the db I only want to get the data that has not been translated yet, that is why the ids are so many - they are those that already have been translated. Is there a way to do this?